# UNSTACK R DATAFRAME base value of another column

Tags: r

Im new to stackoverflow. Currently I am struck on trying to unstack a large data set that i have extracted online using R. There are two columns as seen below one column being ID number and the other being a having a value in this case being probability

Currently my dataset looks something as follows

```
ID number; Probability
      1    ;     0.1
      1    ;     0.2
      1    ;     0.3
      2    ;     0.2
      2    ;     0,1
      2    ;     0.3
      2    ;     0.2
      2    ;     0.8
      n    ;      x
```

I Would like it to look something as follows

```
1        ;     2       ;     n
0.1      ;     0.2     ;      x
0.2      ;     0.1     ;      x
0.3      ;     0.3     ;      x 
NA       ;     0.2     ;      x
NA       ;     0.3     ;     and on and on
```

I have tried the unstack package but could not manage this to work. Anyone has a line of code that I could use or explain how I should do this?

EDIT!; I also see its difficult to see what the dataframe looks like so please see a screenshot made in excell attached

With kind regards,
Sven

Answer (score 2):

If the 'ID' frequency are the same, then use `unstack`

```
unstack(df1, Probability ~ IDnumber)
```

---

If the frequency is not the same, use `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), rowid(IDnumber) ~ IDnumber)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(IDnumber = rep(1:3, each = 5), Probability = rnorm(15))
```