# What is the equivalent of `unstack()` in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, pivot, reshape

I want to convert the long to wide format of my data using data.table. Normally I use `unstack()`, but I don't know how to do it in data.table. Below is an example. As output I expect three columns and three rows.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(class = factor(rep(c("A", "B", "C"), times = 3)),
                 value = runif(9))
unstack(df, form = value ~ class)
#>           A         B         C
#> 1 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534
#> 2 0.9082078 0.2016819 0.8983897
#> 3 0.9446753 0.6607978 0.6291140

dt <- data.table(df)
dcast(dt, formula = value ~ class, value.var = "value")
#>        value         A         B         C
#> 1: 0.2016819        NA 0.2016819        NA
#> 2: 0.2655087 0.2655087        NA        NA
#> 3: 0.3721239        NA 0.3721239        NA
#> 4: 0.5728534        NA        NA 0.5728534
#> 5: 0.6291140        NA        NA 0.6291140
#> 6: 0.6607978        NA 0.6607978        NA
#> 7: 0.8983897        NA        NA 0.8983897
#> 8: 0.9082078 0.9082078        NA        NA
#> 9: 0.9446753 0.9446753        NA        NA
```

Additionally, I don't want to use an aggregate function, but in data.table on real data I see: `Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'`, so there are fewer rows in the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
dcast(dt, rowid(class) ~ class)
#   class         A          B         C
#1:     1 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534
#2:     2 0.9082078 0.2016819 0.8983897
#3:     3 0.9446753 0.6607978 0.6291140
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52501268/10276092

Answer (score 1):

We can try `split` within `dt` like below (but this option is available only if we have the same number of values per class, thus, the [`dcast` option by @M.Viking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74540750/12158757) is recommended for general cases)

```
> dt[, split(value, class)]
           A         B         C
1: 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534
2: 0.9082078 0.2016819 0.8983897
3: 0.9446753 0.6607978 0.6291140
```

Comment: It also seems that `split()` is several times faster than `dcast()` on a larger dataset.

Comment: @nukubiho probably it is true because it doesn't really pivot the original `dt` but re-organized the data by `class`